# DatePicker object in Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm having trouble with Microsoft Access. I get the error "Run-time error '2683', There is no object in this control".

When debugging the database, it seems the line

```
  Me.qStartDate.Value = Me.DTPickerStart.Value
```

is the problem. I've researched this error and it seems that there's a problem because DatePicker is deprecated and does not work on Access 2010. I'm wondering how I can rewrite this to make the function work.

Sorry, I'm a web programmer and I'm not very familiar with Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251104(v=office.14).aspx

It mentions your options:

- Use the built-in DatePicker feature for any TextBox control that is bound to a Date field.
- Use the Windows DatePicker control, part of the Windows Common Controls.
- Use a subform that looks and functions like a calendar.
- Use a third-party date/calendar control.